# How to import the right way in python?

Tags: python, oop, naming, conventions

I am learning python programming and I would like to have some information.
I am working on a small project, using OOP. Here is an example of the project structure:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER  
    |__ main.py  
    |__ modules  
         |__ __init__.py  
         |__ Example.py
```

To import my classes (here just one, but generally more) should I import every file one by one or create an "all" rule in the *__init__.py* file?

Here are my ideas:

```
# Example.py
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello from Example')
```

First Idea:

```
# First version of __init__.py is an empty file
```

```
# First version of main.py
from modules.Example import Example

my_example = Example()
```

Or, second idea:

```
# Second version of __init__.py
__all__ = ['Example']
```

```
# Second version of main.py
from modules import *

my_example = Example.Example()
```

According to what I read in the documentation and here, it's better avoiding the use of `import *` because it could be confusing. But, if I need to import 56 classes, should I write 56 lines to import my classes before starting coding? And, using `import *` would force me to write `my_example = Example.Example()` which is not pretty and could be confusing too.

To conclude, is this better to name class files with the class names (including the capitalized first letter)? I learned that it was a good practice in PHP but python seems to have other convention (snake case for example) that pylint is always happy to remind me :)

Thanks for your answers, have a good day!

Comment: If you have 56 classes in one module, then you should consider refactoring instead of doing wildcard imports.

Comment: Thanks, but it was just an example, not a real life case.

Comment: you could import the module give it an alias and use it to access the classes.
`import modules as mds`
`my_example = mds.Example()`
import the `Example` to `__init__.py`

Comment: this is quite a nice [guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) for python project structures and importing best practices

Comment: A simple rule is to always avoid the * form of import. Use `from x import y... [as name]` for specific names that don't collide in current namespace. Everytime thera are a lot of names keep them under the module name or under a shorter alias.

Comment: This is to be safe. Quick example: never do `from tkinter import *` that has hundreds of names.  Do `import tkinter as tk`. Then use `tk.Button` and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some general conventions when it comes to importing in python. import * is called wild card import and it's best to avoid using wild card imports no matter which programming language you're using. if all of your 56 classes are in one file, you import it like `from my_file import class_1, class_2, ...`. you can use parentheses to make it more cleaner, `from my_file import (class_1, class_2, class_3, ...)` if your classes aren't in one file import them in **init**.py and then you can import all of them in one line like the above example . Another convention to importing in python is to always start from importing standard libraries and then third party packages and finally your own modules. for example

> import sys
>
> import requests
>
> from my_package import some_thing

class in python should be CamelCase and for modules separate words with underscore. `from MyClassName import my_module`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I did not know that I could import from \__init__.py file and that answered the main question.
Thanks for all the information :) !

Comment: Just a nitpick, but `MyClassName` is actually PascalCase, a subcasing of camelCase, often called uppercase camelCase. As another note, if you have subfolders, you can import them as `from somefolder.subfolder.my_package import my_module`. I'm not sure `MyClassName` is neither in appropriate casing, nor named correctly... am I rusty?

Answer (score 1):

> According to what I read in the documentation and here, it's better avoiding the use of import * because it could be confusing.

This is true. Avoid `import *` if you can.

> But, if I need to import 56 classes, should I write 56 lines to import my classes before starting coding?

Yes. But how many files do you foresee using 56 classes?

> And, using import * would force me to write my_example = Example.Example() which is not pretty and could be confusing too.

I think you mean *not* using `import *`, but there's also the `from module import names` syntax, so you can do `from modules.example import Example`, and use `my_example = Example()`.

> To conclude, is this better to name class files with the class names (including the capitalized first letter)? I learned that it was a good practice in PHP but python seems to have other convention (snake case for example) that pylint is always happy to remind me :)

Conventionally, modules are `snake_case.py`, classes are `PascalCase`, names of variables and functions are `snake_case`, and constants are `BIG_SNAKE_CASE`.

Comment: I disagree. `import *` makes you import everything. No need to write code anymore. You just solved the universe, and the output of your program will be 42.